# Is there a way to query google datastore like the CONTAINS filter in GQL?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify, gql

Suppose you have 2 entities of same kind which has a List field
The List field in both entities are like:
First entity has elements such as "a" and "b"
Second entity has only one element "a",
so "a" is common for both entities

When querying i want the second entity alone, is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If it in an array.

Suppose your `json` is like this

```
const v1 = {id: 1, list: ['c', 'a', 'd']})
const v2 = {id: 2, list: ['a','s', 'e']})
```

if you query for `list='a'`, datastore will return both elements.

Comment: yeah, it would return both, but is there a way to get v2 alone while querying with respect to list='a'?

Comment: Yes, you set limit=1, sort descendent by ID and you are ready to go.

Comment: let me ask you this way, i have multiple entities, some of them have list field as ["a","b","c"] and others have list field as ["a,"b"]. So while querying, i want all the entities which has ["a","b"], i don't want the entities which have ["a","b","c"]

Comment: There is not. But you can always save an extra synthetic indexed private field which contains what you are looking for, eg index a "notc" field and filter on that.

Comment: You can use list='a' and list='b' but there is no inequality "<>". So in order to have what you want, use list='a' and list='b', and discard the unwanted value in the server memory.

Comment: Is it worked? Hope you find this answer the right one so you can vote and accept it